# Question about my codes when using the Tokenizer.__init__ in a class

Tags: python

I wish to understand more about why we can use the below code and what does it do?

If possible can anyone explain to me how does `Tokenizer.__init__` work? Since we can attach the "`__init__`" to a library, can we do it with other way too? If possible can someone give me some example so that I could understand, it will be glad if can do another simple example.

My codes:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

// we import the tokenizer library

//Then we build a class

class DataWrapper(Tokenizer):
    def __init__(self, num_words):
        Tokenizer.__init__(self, num_words=num_words) // I dont understand how this part work.
self.fit_on_texts(texts)
            self.tokens = self.texts_to_sequences(texts)
            self.reverse_tokens = dict(zip(self.word_index.values(),
                                           self.word_index.keys()))

            if reverse:
                self.tokens = [list(reversed(token)) for token in self.tokens]

            self.num_tokens = [len(token) for token in self.tokens]
            self.max_num = np.mean(self.num_tokens) + 2 * np.std(self.num_tokens)
            self.max_num = int(self.max_num)
            self.sequences_padded = pad_sequences(self.tokens, maxlen=self.max_num,
                                                  padding=padding,


                            truncating=truncating)
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, all functions with `self` can be called in two ways: obj.method(params) or, cls.method(obj, params). See this example:

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        print('foo')

a = A()
# now we can call foo function in two ways:
a.foo()
A.foo(a)
```

This rule works also for function with double underscore like `__init__`. In your case:

```
Tokenizer.__init__(self, num_words=num_words)

cls = Tokenizer
method = __init__
obj = self  # object of class DataWrapper
params = num_words
```

Comment: Thank you sir but I dont get it. I thought my class was DataWrapper and Tokenizer was a library that I imported?

Comment: I think I get what it means, the class DataWrapper is actually to wrap the whole class as the function of Tokenizer library.

Comment: @kingkongmanoftheworldinchaos No, `Tokenizer` is not a library.

Comment: No no... You imported only a class. `Tokenizer` in your case is a class.
In python, you can import the whole module (library) `import tensorflow`. Or only some part of the module `from tensorflow import something`. Something can be actually anything. It can be class, method, variable, etc.